# How to use two APIs to get the response of an endpoint once it processed?

Tags: python, api, url, request

I have two APIs: `triggerAPI` and `triggerAPIResult`. When I hit the first one, it would trigger a process which could take a few minutes to return the response. The second API is used to check if the process is successfully finished or not.

Therefore, when the second API returns true, that means now the response from the first API is the desired output. The second API response is very important since when the first API is still processing, it would return meaningless data until actually finished. Another thing is that the  `triggerAPIResult` API should get triggered every `minute` for `10 minutes` to constantly check the result. How could you I implement this in Python?

Comment: It is not easier the first API just answer received and the second API answer result not ready or the actual result when it is ready?

Comment: Are we talking about rest apis here? Does triggerAPIResult only exist to let the client know that the first request was processed? Couldn't you just await the response? https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: @William yes they're REST APIs. the thing is that the ```triggerAPI``` would immediately return some HTML but it is not the desired output. it will return the useful result once it has successfully finished.

Comment: Are you building the APIs in this situation, or the client or both? If you're building the APIs, I wouldn't split it up over two endpoints like that, I would just have it return either "here's your data" or "your data isn't ready yet." If these APIs already exist and you're building the client, then you just need to hit the second one every 10m right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement long running operations. This is an implementation strategy used by fe. Google (in [their](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/samples/compute-instances-operation-check) [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/operations/wait) [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/how-tos/long-running-operations)), [IBM](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/api-handbook?topic=api-handbook-long-running-operations), and other big companies.

The principle is quite simple.

1. Do a request to the `triggerAPI` and immediately return a unique operation ID.
2. Store this ID somewhere and have an `is_done` value tied to it which is set to `False`.
3. Have whatever logic was triggered do its thing. Once it's done, update the operation and set the `is_done` value to `True`. Store the result of the operation somewhere.
4. Call the `triggerAPIResult` and have logic to check the state of the operation. Return the actual processed data when done, otherwise return something like `still working`.

---

Note that the actual implementation can be a bit complicated depending on the tech used. I would go for microservices in this scenario to avoid having to use threads or async.

- External API with the two endpoints you mentioned.
- Internal API that does the actual data processing.
- NoSQL backend that stores the operation status' and the result of the data processing.